# IIS 10 can't load pictures with port 80, but can load with port 8080

Tags: iis, localhost, port

Thanks:

If use port 80:
[image: If use port 80:]
Error message:
[image: Error message:]
If use port 8080, everything works:
[image: If use port 8080, everything works:]
Update ————————————————————

[image]
[image]
Update ————————————————————
If I visit iisstart.png:

[image]
Use Telerik Fiddler:
[image]

Comment: Read Network tab please.

Comment: did you see your png file loaded in IIS log? If there was an log entry, please post its status-substatus code.  But your symptom looks just like the image get blocked by something. The best way to troubleshooting this issue is capture ETL log. For the beginning, please tell me whether the request to load png file have reach IIS.

Comment: thanks for answer, sorry, I forgot upload the network tab, now updated...

Comment: I have never seen this before. Do you have third-party module injected in IIS worker process? You could check it with process monitor.

Comment: Then Chrome is useless here that it cannot tell you much about why it fails. Can you try to use Fiddler? https://www.telerik.com/fiddler As a proxy it should record better results on what exactly happens on the wire.

Comment: Thanks, Lex Li, I updated, can you help me?